# Remove all occurence of ';' in C++ comments with SED

Tags: sed, comments, character-replacement

I'm new to `sed` and I can't manage to use it to remove all ';' characters in comments of C++ files, ie lines starting or containing the string "//" (I already convert "/* ... */" comments to "// ..." comments).

For example :

```
// lorem; ipsum ; test
int a; // 1 ; 2 ; 3 ;
```

And I want to have :

```
// lorem ipsum  test
int a; // 1  2  3
```

For any comment in my C++ files.

********* EDIT *********

Here is a solution with SED in two steps. A solution with AWK is also available in answers.

1. Put all comments on a new line : `sed 's/\/\//\n\/\//g'`
2. Remove ';' only on lines starting by "//" : `sed '/^\/\// s/;//g'`

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward in AWK. Create a file **r.awk**:

```
function process(s) {
    gsub(";", "", s)
    return s
}

{
    sep = "//"; ns=length(sep)
    m = match($0, sep)
    if (!m) {print; next}

    body = substr($0,    1, m-1)
    cmnt = substr($0, m+ns     )

    print body sep process(cmnt)
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f r.awk input.file
```

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed straightforward with AWK.

I finally manage to do it with SED in two steps :
1. Put all comments on a new line : `sed 's/\/\//\n\/\//g'`
2. Remove ';' only on lines starting by "//" : `sed '/^\/\// s/;//g'`